# PropertyInfo.GetValue returns int, but casting to decimal results in InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net

we have the following code which produces an unexpected result (probably because we don't understand something fundamental that's going on here).

```
var propInfo = propObj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.PropertyName);
var valueobj = propInfo.GetValue(obj); /* valueobj now contains the number 0*/ 
var valueDecimal = (decimal) valueobj; /* this produces an InvalidCastException
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how to fix this code? In any case we want to get the decimal value, even if it is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first unbox the int and then you can convert it to decimal

```
var propInfo = propObj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.PropertyName);
var valueInt = (int)propInfo.GetValue(obj); /* valueobj now contains the number 0*/ 
var valueDecimal = (decimal) valueInt;
```

Although the syntax is the same the conversion between object and int is actually an unboxing operation, if you try to convert object to decimal it tries to unbox a decimal and thus fails.

**Internals**

If we look in the generated IL for the version in the question and the version above, we can more clearly see the difference:

For the original this is what the cast to decimal generates:

```
unbox.any [mscorlib]System.Decimal
```

For the version above:

```
call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Implicit(int32)
```

Comment: It can also be done in a single line: `(decimal)(int)propInfo.GetValue(obj)`, although it's arguably less clear like this.

Comment: @GabrielNegut yes you are right it can be don like that as well, but I thought it more clear to separate the lines